# Converting dd-MMM-yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy format

Tags: java, sql-server

I have date string as "02-SEP-2012". I want to convert it to 8/02/2012 format.

```
String deliverydate="02-SEP-2012";
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

Date date=sdf.parse(deliveryDate);
```

This gives me

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01-Sep-2012"
```

How to parse this?
I want to insert this date in MS SQL.

Comment: Replace "/" with "-"? SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

Comment: Septembre, 2nd to February, 8th? Oô...

Comment: even this gives the same exception.

Comment: Sorry. The letters must be adjusted too.  SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 2018/Java 10

```
String deliverydate="02-SEP-2012";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy")
                .toFormatter(Locale.UK);
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(deliverydate, formatter);
System.out.println(ld);
```

## Original answer

Look at the two Strings, `02-SEP-2012` and `MM/dd/yyyy` - these are not the same format.

The date parser is expecting the String to be in the same format as the formatter

```
String deliverydate="02-SEP-2012";
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

Date date=sdf.parse(deliveryDate);

sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(deliveryDate);
```

then to re-format:

```
sdf.applyPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Comment: If i use this,while inserting it into db it gives org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: args and argTypes parameters must match

Comment: Check your insert code, the return type here is `java.util.Date` but the re-arranged output is just String formatting.

Comment: @sonam What does that have to do with your question?

Answer (score 1):

in sql server:

You could use  convert() function..

You can try

```
Insert into <table> (date_col,<othercolumns>)
select CONVERT(date,'02-SEP-2012'),<othercolumns>
```

Example:

```
declare @date varchar(20) ='02-SEP-2012'
select CONVERT(date,@date)
```

result:

```
2012-09-02
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String deliverydate="02-SEP-2012";
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Date date=sdf.parse(deliveryDate);
```

Did you try this "- " instead of "/".

Answer (score 0):

Using the parse(String source) method can throw java.text.ParseException exception if the supplied date is not in a valid format.So you should use valid format.